# Object access in Jsp page

Tags: java, jsp

I have form page in which has fields name and age, I'm submitting this form to a servlet which insert these values in the database if there are no errors, if there are errors I'm returning the back to the form page. On return I'm also passing an object of the java class as shown below as attribute

```
class details{
     private String name;
     private int age;

     public void setName(String name){
          this.name=name;
     }
     public String getName(){
          return this.name;
     }
     public void setAge(int name){
          this.age=age;
     }
     public String getAge(){
          return this.age;
     }
 }
```

Since all the class variables are private we will not be able to access the variable outside the class without using the getters and setters. If i pass an object of this class as attribute to the form page I can access it using (Suppose attributeName is the name of the attribute passed)

```
attributeName.name, attributeName.age
```

This might be a bad question but bear with me or steer me right, won't the access as above violate the private feature of the class allowing access of the object property outside the class

Comment: I believe that the JSP actually USE the getter. It's just a syntax sugar

Comment: No problem of violation at all. Java use introspection to retreive getter and setter. You could experiment it by removing the getter and setter and your code will not work anymore.

Comment: You can refer http://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info for information about Expression Language and how it gets translated to actual code

Comment: Thank you for the explanations @Jérôme Gloaguen